# How to load a image with absolute path in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react-app I want to load images with an absolute path. I get the path as a string from an api response. So its not possible to put image folder in the src oder public folder. I read several stackoverflow-question but nothing helped so far.
The path I'm getting looks like this

```
"\\SRMS508\Dokumente\1\Artikel\Art.Nr 100085\100085_CIMG7224.JPG"
```

And neither this:

```
<img src="\\SRMS508\\Dokumente\1\Artikel\Art.Nr 100085\100085_CIMG7224.JPG"/>
```

not this:

```
<img src={require("\\SRMS508\\Dokumente\1\Artikel\Art.Nr 100085\100085_CIMG7224.JPG").default} />
```

is working.

And I would be very happy if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: you need to set path relative from where you are rendering

Answer (score 2):

If you keep your images in the public folder where we keep all static assets like images then we can access them as:

> Folder: public/images/

```html
<img src="/images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Thats the problem. I can't keep the images in the public folder.

Comment: then If you use svg you can import as component where relate path can work but it won't work for jpg